# Integration in solving coin toss problem via Bayesian appoach

Tags: probability, integration, bayesian

The following is taken from [here](http://www.behind-the-enemy-lines.com/2008/01/are-you-bayesian-or-frequentist-or.html):

> You have a coin that when flipped ends up head with probability $p$ and
>   ends up tail with probability $1−p$. (The value of p is unknown.)
>
> Trying to estimate $p$, you flip the coin $14$ times. It ends up head $10$
>   times.
>
> Then you have to decide on the following event: "In the next two
>   tosses we will get two heads in a row."
>
> What is the probability the event will happen?

In attempting to solve this via a bayesian approach, the author first derives a distribution for $p$, whose plot is below:

[image]

He then states that to find the probability of two heads, the following needs to be computed:

$$Pr\left(HH|\text{data}\right) = \int_0^1 Pr\left(HH|p\right) \cdot Pr\left(p|\text{data}\right) dp$$

I'm unclear on how the integrand was arrived at though.

I understand that you need to need to sum up $Pr(HH|p)$ across all $p$ from 0 to 1, but why do you multiply this by the other terms?

Comment: Because you need to weight $P(HH|p)$ by likelihood of $p$. If $P(p|data)=0$ you don't want to add that $P(HH|p)$ for that value of $p$. Sidenote: the author is incorrect to assume $a=b=1$. A more reasonable assumption is $a=b=0$ or at least $a=b=1/2$.

Comment: @A.S. Ah that makes sense. Why does $a=b=0$ provide a better assumption though?

Comment: @A.S. Is there also any mathematical justification for the weighting by multiplication? Like some sort of proof by conditional probability or bayes' theorem? Or is this just a definition of bayesian stats?

Comment: It's the Law of Total Probability.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Wouldn't applying the law of total probability only give you that $Pr(HH|p) \cdot Pr(p)$ summed across all $p$ gives $Pr(HH)$? How would you add in the condition for $Pr(p|data)$?

Comment: No, it's because for a given value of $p$ the event and data are conditionally independent:  $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(\textsf{event}\mid \textsf{data}) 
& = \int_0^1 \mathsf P(\textsf{event}\mid p=\phi, \textsf{data})\mathsf P(p=\phi\mid \textsf{data})\operatorname d \phi & \textrm{total probability}
\\[1ex] & = \int_0^1 \mathsf P(\textsf{event}\mid p=\phi)\mathsf P(p=\phi\mid \textsf{data})\operatorname d \phi & \textrm{conditional independence}
\end{align}$$

Comment: It's a long discussion as to what prior properly reflects our lack of "knowledge". Uniform prior ($a=b=1$) implicitly assumes that you have already seen the coin land both H and T once. But you haven't - it's possible that the coin is thrown in such a way that it never lands H. Improper prior $a=b=0$ reflects that lack of knowledge and is invariant. Prior $a=b=1/2$ is inbetween these two and is proper.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Why is $event$ and $p = \phi$ conditionally independent of $data$?

Comment: @1110101001 The $\sf event$ and the $\sf data$ are conditionally independent given $p=\phi$. $\;$ Because, the original $14$ trials that gave the $\sf data$ and the $2$ *new* trials for the $\sf event$ are presumed to have no common influence *other* than the bias of the coin.

Comment: http://www.boostedsignal.com/blog/963ccd59-b007-45e4-9213-b510b11505a7.html